# How to use self referential foreign key in Rust Diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I created a self referential table and I want to use it with Rust Diesel v2.x.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Identifiable, Queryable, Selectable)]
#[diesel(table_name = modality)]
pub struct Modality {
    pub id: i32,
    pub ... wathever ...
    pub reply_to: i32  // Foreign key to Modality
}
```

But I haven't found much information on how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can find an example in this [issue](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/2613) (although with an old version of the syntax) and some hints in the official documentation in the [association page](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/associations/index.html).

It works the same way as when you write a foreign key (use `belongs_to` and `i32`) but most people don't name their self-referential column `{table_name}_id` so you must tell diesel which column is the foreign key. Here's an excerpt from the documentation:

> By default, Diesel assumes that your foreign keys will follow the convention `table_name_id`. If your foreign key has a different name, you can provide the `foreign_key` argument to `#[diesel(belongs_to)]`.

Here's an example:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Identifiable, Queryable, Selectable)]
#[diesel(table_name = modality)]
#[diesel(belongs_to(Modality, foreign_key = reply_to))]
pub struct Modality {
    pub id: i32,
    pub ... wathever ...
    pub reply_to: i32  // Or Option<i32> if nullable
}
```